# PHP Regex matching only some letters/words and punctuation

Tags: php, regex

Not sure if this is the right approach, so chime in if you have something better:

I have a series of data codes that I need to match against. The codes themselves are being scraped and split off of other text but their location and tagging with that text is only about 70% consistent. I figure using regex might be a better approach for getting not just the outliers but all of them, since the codes are pretty standard, but I'm not sure how to target strings with only "certain" letters/parenthesis/asterix/etc. Here are my test examples:

```
3-301.11(C)*
3-501.16 (Cold)
5-202.11(A)
3-501.16 (Hot)
6-501.111(C)*
7-201.11(A)*
```

Most of the codes come back fine as:

```
5-103.11
```

I am able to use this expression `^[0-9]+[-]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[.]+[0-9]+[0-9]` to target most of these but the endings are throwing me off

I have the samples setup here:

https://regexr.com/3smmj

**EDIT**

Just tried out Frank's solution to add (.*) to my, which worked, but opened a new issue. Since these codes are embedded in text, my test samples should have included additional text after the codes. I have updated the link/test examples.

**SOLUTION**
Thanks to everyone for the help. I updated the link with the (now) working solution.

```
^\d+-\d+\.\d+(?:\s*\([^()]*\)\*?)?
```

Comment: Do you need [`^\d+-\d+\.\d+(?:\s*\([^()]*\)\*?)?`](https://regex101.com/r/OA1K61/1)? Add any string inside parentheses with an optional asterisk after?

Comment: Just adding `(.*)` right after your own solution does the job I think? If that is what you meant to do? Combine it with Utkanos' solution to get `\d+-\d+\.\d+(.*)`

Comment: Ok wow. Thanks! I assume the d's are matching numbers, and then the ending part just grabs whatever is left after that until a space?

Comment: You guessed that right :-). The dot stands for any character. The asterisk for 0 or more repeats.

Comment: Looks good but I just realized an error in my example and updated the link. See edit above.

Comment: Whoa @WiktorStribiżew worked a charm. Thanks! Post your solution as an answer and I'll mark it done!

Comment: @mrpatg Posted with explanations below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
'~^\d+-\d+\.\d+(?:\s*\([^()]*\)\*?)?~m'
```

Or, to match anywhere on a line:

```
'~\b\d+-\d+\.\d+(?:\s*\([^()]*\)\*?)?~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OA1K61/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line (replace with `\b` word boundary if you need to match anywhere on a line)
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `-` -  a hyphen
- `\d+\.\d+` - 1+ digits, `.` and 1+ digits
- `(?:\s*\([^()]*\)\*?)?` - an optional sequence of patterns matching

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `\(` - a `(`
  - `[^()]*` - 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
  - `\)` - a `)`
  - `\*?` - an optional asterisk symbol.

Example of PHP code:

```
if (preg_match_all('~\b\d+-\d+\.\d+(?:\s*\([^()]*\)\*?)?~', $s, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write it out, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

From the codes you've shown you can simplify this pattern quite a bit:

```
/\d+-\d+\.\d+/
```

Explanation:

- one or more numbers
- then a dash
- one or more numbers
- then a period
- one or more numbers

Note there is no need to put single characters in `[]` as you did; in fact, `[-]` will be misinterpreted because `-` inside `[]` are interpreted as range operators, e.g. `[0-9]`.